# WDS: Disconnected! loop when running webpack-dev-server simultaneously

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, multiple-instances

Here is my use case. 
Several instances of **webpack-dev-servers, running simultaneously** on shared server everyone is serving content on its one port.

At some point, every site falls into **[WDS] Disconnected! loop**. It's not clear to me where's the breaking point, but obviously, it correlates with the number of WDS instances.

So my question is where's the bottleneck RAM, CPU, too many WebSocket connections? Maybe it is a configuration thing?

Have you ever encountered a similar problem?

Is there a way to fix it? I mean besides working on local machine:)

- node: 8.9.1
- webpack: 3.5.5
- webpack-dev-server: 2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

In `webpacker.yml` file use the following settings for `dev_server` on `development` env.:

```
  dev_server:
    host: '127.0.0.0'
    port: 8080
    https: false
    disableHostCheck: true
```

Comment: That won't do, I need that SSL connection.